# How do I get LinkedIn to email my new primary email address?

Tags: account-management, linkedin

I've recently changed the main email address I use.  I put the new address into LinkedIn, confirmed it, and made it primary.  But LinkedIn still sends me all its email on the address that I had first joined it with (which is still active, so I don't want to remove it.)  How do I get LinkedIn's messages to come to my new primary email address?

Answer (score 1):

You could try unsetting your message receiving settings and then setting them back. I changed my email not too long ago also, and have email still going to my old address (which is not a problem for me). I did notice upon joining a new group that the group digests go to my new email address.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you seem to have followed the correct process.

I assume that you can distinguish the emails. So it is not possible that you have a forward set-up outside of LinkedIn.

Otherwise, as you say you have multiple active emails, I would suggest changing the primary email back to your original one (that still gets the emails).  Wait for "1 day" then try again.  ( Wait 1 day if this is not urgent, otherwise an hour should be plenty for back-end systems... assuming that there is actually some kind of lag )

Comment: I tried this, and unfortunately, it did not work.  Emails still come to the old address.

Answer (score -1):

Are you having this problem 24 hours after you changed your primary email address?

According to the [LinkedIn suport site](http://linkedin.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/linkedin.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=2919&p_created=1261613974&p_sid=UUYqZV6k&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9Mzk4LDM5OCZwX3Byb2RzPTAmcF9jYXRzPSZwX3B2PSZwX2N2PSZwX3BhZ2U9MSZwX3NlYXJjaF90ZXh0PUdldHRpbmcgVXBkYXRlcyBhdCBPbGQgQWRkcmVzcyBhZnRlciBDaGFuZ2luZyBQcmltYXJ5IEVtYWls&p_li=&p_topview=1), changes to your primary email address should take effect within 24 hours.

Comment: It's been weeks since I changed the primary email address, and the emails are still coming to my old one.